# read -p "a\n" VARIABLE does not create a new line

Tags: bash

Trying to execute this command:

```
read -p "Insert user/repo, example: SirVer/ultisnips\n" GITREPO
```

The problem is that

```
read -p "a\n" VARIABLE
```

isn't creating a new line.

Any ideas without using echo? I don't want to add a line of code just for that.

Comment: `read -p $'a\nb'`, same way as any other newline literal works.

Comment: :_ why that $ symbol helps here? @CharlesDuffy

Comment: ...with respect to the dollar sign, `$'...'` is an ANSI C-like string. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks man